# How can I show line numbers in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, configuration

How can I show line numbers *by default* in Eclipse?

Comment: What do you mean, "by default"?  For each new workspace?  For each new install of eclipse?  I'm confused.

Comment: @Uri: Ehm, so that when you get an error message thrown at you by the compiler you can quickly find the line by scanning the document with your eyes.

Comment: @X-lstence ctrl-l will bring up a pop up box where you can enter a line number to jump to

Comment: Still I find it much faster when using a tool like lint to scroll to each line when there are multiple errors and having a way to show line numbers is invaluable. Also when taking screenshots it can be nice to see the original line numbers for discussion purposes.

Comment: Big News! (reported by Lars VOGEL): starting 4.4M4, line numbers are activated *by default*! See [my (edited) answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/641540/6309)

Answer (score 1113):

*Window → Preferences → General → Editors → Text Editors → Show line numbers*.

---

Edit: I wrote this long ago but as @ArtOfWarfar and @voidstate mentioned you can now simply:

Right click the gutter and select "Show Line Numbers":

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the Juno release and eventually found it under eclipse -> preference -> general -> editors -> text editors -> show line numbers.

Comment: In Eclipse for Mac, it's not in Window->Preferences but in Eclipse->Preferences

Comment: @CJDennis Or you can just type "line" or even "line number" in the search bar of the preferences. That's something they did do right. Besides that it *is* in a logical location.

Answer (score 483):

If this doesn't work it may be overridden by your current settings. You can right-click in the bar to the left of the code where line numbers would normally appear and turn them on with the context menu.

[image: Screen showing this context menu]

Answer (score 95):

Update November 2015:

### In Eclipse Mars 4.5.1, line numbers are (annoyingly) turned off by default again. Follow the below instructions to enable it.

---

Update December 2013:

[Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/people/larsvogel.html) just [published on his blog](http://blog.vogella.com/2013/12/10/line-numbers-are-default-in-eclipse-sdk-luna-as-of-today/):

### Line numbers are default in Eclipse SDK Luna (4.4) as of today

(December 10, 2013)

> We conducted a user survey if users want to have line numbers activated in text editors in the Eclipse IDE by default.
> The response was very clear:

```
YES : 80.07% (1852 responses)
NO  : 19.93% (461 responses)
Total  : 2313
Skipped:   15
```

> With [Bug 421313](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421313), [Review - Line number should be activated by default](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/18233/), we enabled it for the Eclipse SDK build, I assume other Eclipse packages will follow.

---

Update August 2014

**Line number default length** is now **120** (instead of 80) for Eclipse Mars 4.5M1.
See "[How to customize Eclipse's text editor code formating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25250064/6309)".

---

Original answer (March 2009)

To really have it by default, you can write a script which ensure, before launching eclipse, that:
**`[workspace]\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs`** does contain:

```
lineNumberRuler=true
```

(with `[workspace]` being the root directory of your eclipse workspace)
Then eclipse will be opened with "line numbers shown 'by default' "

---

Otherwise, you can also type 'CTRL+1' and then "line", which will give you access to the command "Show line numbers"
(that will switch to option "show line numbers" in the text editors part of the option.

Or you can just type "numb" in Windows Preferences to access to the Text Editor part:

[image: show line number]

<sup>Picture from "[How to display line numbers in Eclipse](http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-display-line-numbers-in-eclipse/)" of blog "[Mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/)"</sup>

Comment: On the current Eclipse Mars version (4.5.1), line numbers are not enabled by default (annoyingly).

Comment: How can I set left indent spacing, to add some space between line number and the first character of each line?

Comment: @Ωmega 10 years later, I don't know. that would be space or padding between the gutter and the code editor.

Answer (score 30):

As simple as that.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, then <kbd>N</kbd>, to Show or hide line numbers.

Reference : http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html

Comment: One need to have focus in the Editor for that shortcut to work, but that is pretty obvious if one reads the section title in the referred article. :-)

Answer (score 25):

Slight variation on Mac OSX:
Eclipse → Preferences → General → Editors → Text Editors → Show line numbers

Answer (score 20):

Windows → Preferences → General → Text Editors → Show numberlines

Answer (score 19):

in this file

[workspace].metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs

make sure the parameter

lineNumberColor=0,0,0

is NOT 255,255, 255, which is white

Comment: Does that mean you can have different colors of line numbers? Interesting. I will try that sometime soon.

Answer (score 19):

Go to Windows → Preferences → General → Text Editors → Show numberlines. Click OK, then Apply changes. Then it will show the line count automatically.

Answer (score 9):

one of the easy way is using shortcuts like : Ctrl+F10, then press n "it show line number and hide line numbers.

Answer (score 7):

The top answer is good but you can also bind it to a key ( shorcut ) to toggle it..

Window > Preferences > Keys then enter "Line Numbers" in filter and bind it to a key.

I use CTRL + S + L.

Answer (score 7):

Open Eclipse

goto -> Windows -> Preferences -> Editor -> Text Editors -> Show Line No

Tick the **Show Line No** checkbox

Answer (score 4):

***click on window tab and click on preferences***

[image: click on window tab]

***do this and check show line number***

[image: check show line number]

Answer (score 3):

the eclipse changes the perferences's position

to eclipse -> perferences

Answer (score 3):

On a Mac do this:

```
cmd + , or ADT -> Preferences
```

Expand General -> Editors ->Text Editors

```
Check box: Show line numbers
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse has a search feature in the top left box of the Preferences. 
Type in 'line numbers' in that search box, and presto...

In case you're tired of googling each time you forget...

Answer (score 1):

this will be the appropriate solution for asked question:

String lineNumbers =
AbstractDecoratedTextEditorPreferenceConstants.EDITOR_LINE_NUMBER_RULER;
EditorsUI.getPreferenceStore().setValue(lineNumbers, true);