# Eclipse: Set maximum line length for auto formatting right?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

I make all according this question:
[Eclipse: Set maximum line length for auto formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697287/eclipse-set-maximum-line-length-for-auto-formatting).

my result:
[image]

I tryed to make own profile. profile  was created:

[image]

before  ctrl+shift+f :
[image]

after:

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: It looks like you're formatting XML, but those are the options for *Java* formatting...

Comment: It is true. and how to set maximum length for xml?

Comment: Look in the XML preferences section instead of the Java preferences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Goto [How to Change the Default Format Settings in Eclipse](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Format-Settings-in-Eclipse)

Follow the steps to create a new profile. Step 11 [Line Wrapping] shows a 'Maximum line width' field, changing that would fix your issue.

Also, make sure your newly created profile is selected in the Active Profile drop-down inside
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter.

If you are trying to format XML:
Goto Window -> Preferences -> XML -> XML Files -> Editor
and change Line width field.

Answer (score 1):

right answer:
[image]

P.S. thanks **Jon Skeet**

Answer (score 0):

**You must have to create your own profile**

In eclipse `Window-> preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter`, edit the profile. Under the `Line Wrapping tab` there is the option for line width (`Maximum line width`)

Answer (score 0):

In preferences **Java -> Code Style -> Formatter**, if you don't have your own existing profile then create new with Eclipse[built-in] or select and edit the profile. Under the Line Wrapping tab is the option for line width (Maximum line width:).