# Eclipse line wrapping not wrapping

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

I have a laptop with 1366 horizontal resolution. Sometimes when I program in eclipse the line gets very long. I used to use wing IDE, which had built in line wrapping, where if the line went past a certain number of characters, it would go onto the next line, but it wouldn't take up another "line" in the line count. Furthermore, in any other basic text editor it appeard as only one line. This is what I want; purely a text formatting feature where long lines are wrapped around to the next without affecting the source file.

In eclipse 4.4.2, using the java perspective I tried to enable line wrapping using the guide found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697287/eclipse-set-maximum-line-length-for-auto-formatting) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790193/how-to-customize-eclipses-text-editor-code-formating/25250064#25250064).

The result is less than expected as it seems to have had no effect. (The grey line is the "page width", which is at 115 characters) [album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EXrw.jpg)

You can see the line wrapping page in Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter > Edit

Am I missing something to make the java perspective actually use line wrapping universally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those preferences only apply when you run the *Formatter*, not as you type. There is no built-in bullet-proof way to soft-wrap lines.