# Java: Are The Line Numbers in Eclipse the Same as in the Command Line?

Tags: java, eclipse

Just want to make sure as I'm getting some weird line numbers. Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about the exception line numbers?

Comment: Is there a possibility that something changed outside Eclipse since the last time you started it or refreshed the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line numbers are line numbers - wherever the program starts, that 's line 1. If you need to show them in Eclipse, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640884/eclipse-line-numbers)

Comment: Thanks. wasn't sure if Eclipse altered them in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are. Did you run the compiler again before starting the programm after doing changes?

Comment: Yup, but that wasn't the issue here. Thanks though!