# How to disable annoying bar on left of the editor in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

how to disable the blue box shown on the picture in eclipse.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It's to show a class' method scoping.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640884/eclipse-line-numbers

Answer (score 15):

Go to Preferences->General->Text Editors. Disable "Show range indicator".