# Eclipse background color unexpected behaviour

Tags: eclipse, customization, ide-customization

I am trying to change background color for Eclipse. I want the editor background to be completely black. To make the UI respond I first have to choose a random color, as I do at step A in the picture. Then I can choose black, click Apply and I get the desired color as seen at step B. But as soon as I exit the settings dialog, the color changes back to step C. It looks like eclipse thinks the grey-ish color is actually black, I don't know. Does anyone know how to deal with this?

[eclipse pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY0ma.png)

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: @takendarkk the scope for this site includes "Software development tools", which the question seems to be about. If you still have specific concerns about the question, no problem, but please voice them with reference to the site's guidelines. You may wish to consider why this is less of a programming question than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640884/how-can-i-show-line-numbers-in-eclipse, for example.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said if people don't like it they should flag me.

Comment: Good job so far. My comments are still here and still coming...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best answer but I found a way to fix it. Im using moonrise theme.

Opened eclipse/plugins/ and found com.github.eclipseuitheme.themes.moonrise-ui,
opened the jar file and edited the moonrise-ui-standalone_WIN.css file (yes im using windows 10, 64 bit (if that has anything to do with it(there were several similiarly named files)))

changed this block:

```
.MPartStack.active #org-eclipse-e4-ui-compatibility-editor Canvas > * > * {
 background-color: #000000;
 }
```

Now it seems to work just fine with black background.